# What does ~ before a file name represent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, filenames

I have a Rails project and I'm using git version control. Currently I have two files, `~edit.html.haml` and `~new.html.haml`. I'm imagining that the `~` has to do with git in some way. My question is what is the `~` for? Is this a mistake made my a previous developer or does this have to do with git?

Comment: Probably caused by the text editor the previous developer used. Files with a ~ are often backup files.

Comment: Where in your Rails project are those files located? Are the same filenames without the ~ in the same location?

Comment: They are found in the views and they are in the same location. I assume it would be safe to remove these files if the are backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a backup (temporary) file. In my experience, backup files are usually deleted whenever the program that created it is closed: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000527.htm

Comment: Temporary files shouldn't be confused with backup files. In many editors (at least in the Unix tradition), a true backup file is created with a `~` at the *end* of its filename; such files persist after the editor is closed, in case the user wants to go back to the previous version (and isn't using source control).